# C compiling in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, visual-studio-code

When I try to run my Hello World Project, VSC tells me:

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\frase\Desktop\test\" && gcc main.c -o main && "c:\Users\frase\Desktop\test\"main
>   Der Befehl "gcc" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
>   konnte nicht gefunden werden.

I installed the Coderunner and C/C++ extension and more

[image: Screenshot]

Do I need to specify the path to the compiler somewhere or what am I doing wrong?

I am thankful for any help.
Regards

Comment: `what am I doing wrong` - You are using Visual Studio Code for C programming ;)

Comment: @caxapexac Whats wrong with VSC? :)

Comment: The error indicates that it can't find `gcc`. Is `gcc` in your PATH?

Comment: @Philipp, just rofling it's pretty good but there are other more comfortable-c-special-IDEs exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow all these steps? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

> Note: The C/C++ extension does not include a C++ compiler or debugger. You will need to install these tools or use those already installed on your computer. Popular C++ compilers are mingw-w64 for Windows, Clang for XCode for macOS, and GCC on Linux. Make sure your compiler executable is in your platform path so the extension can find it. The extension also supports the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I would recommend to use another software for C programming to get started, such as [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (With mingw preinstalled).